# checking for Plugin's existence with PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there a way I can check via phoneGap.js if my plugin is there or not? I want my app to have conditional logic so it doesn't use my plugin's content if it isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the window.PhoneGap.resources Object:

> window.PhoneGap.resources

```
Object
•  accelerometer: true
•  app: true
•  base: true
•  battery: true
•  camera: true
•  capture: true
•  compass: true
•  contact: true
•  crypto: true
•  device: true
•  file: true
•  filetransfer: true
•  geolocation: true
•  media: true
•  network: true
•  notification: true
•  position: true
•  storage: true
•  __proto__: Object
```

Comment: How to look at window.PhoneGap.resources? ```<script type="text/javascript">
      console.log(window.PhoneGap.resources);``` doesn't show it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof window.plugins.myplugin !== 'undefined'){
   // plugin is available
}
```

Comment: That requires I've put 'myplugin' in the xml file. Is there a way to check for an plugin entry in PhoneGap.plist from phonegap.js? I've written a PluginManager 'plugin' that can query this plist file but it seems like it should be able to do this already. My PhoneGap app has logic that will try using various functionality only if the native side has implemented such a plugin.